# How am I using CA2W incorrectly?

Tags: char, tchar

Please could someone explain why this does not work?

```
char *test = "test";
_TCHAR *szTest = CA2W(test);
```

And please tell me what I should be doing instead.

Instead of giving me equal text, it's giving me:

```
﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾﻾
```

Comment: This takes a copy of a pointer that is owned by an object (CA2W) that is about to be destroyed. When that gets destroyed the pointer `szTest` becomes a dangling/stray pointer, which is very dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN, that is bad. So I have used this instead:

```
char *test = "test";
CA2W szTest(test);
```

From here, we can get an LPWSTR type if we really want:

```
LPWSTR test = szTest.m_psz;
```

It also seems better to use LPWSTR instead of _TCHAR * - but I'm not sure (I think they're essentially the same thing, but could be wrong).

Comment: LPWSTR and _TCHAR* aren't always the same. W in LPWSTR tells you it's a wide string (2 bytes per character). T in _TCHAR tells you the size depends on whether you're compiling your project with unicode or multibyte character sets (in project settings), in which cases there will be 1 or 2 bytes per character depending on your build settings.

Comment: You mean 1/2 bytes per code point (if indeed you have Unicode UTF-8/16 for both character types.